# Can't delete data. concatenated dropdown list, not same in my query

Tags: php

Im deleting employee from database. I have the dropdown list data from database concatenated with employee_id. I have to problem in my query so I can match the details from dropdown to my query. How can I concat the where clause?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="employeesdelete.php">
    <input type="hidden" id="empid" name="id">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
    <center><h2>Do you want to delete?</h2><hr></center>
    <div>
        <center>
            <select name="optemployee" required id="soflow">
                <option value="" selected>- Select Employee -</option>
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbname = "dbamps";

//create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword,$dbname);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employees";
$query = $conn->query($sql);
while($prow = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<option value='".$prow['employee_id']."'>".$prow['firstname'].' '.$prow['lastname'].' - '.$prow['employee_id'];"</option>";
}
?>
            </select>
        </center><br>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large" name="deleteemp" value="You're Fired!">
</form>             


<?php
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root");
    if(!$conn)
        die('Cannot connect to the server!'.mysql_error()); 

    mysqli_select_db($conn,"dbamps");


    $temp1= $_POST["optemployee"];

    $sql="DELETE FROM employees WHERE = '$temp1'";

    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    mysqli_close($conn);

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
    echo 'alert("Employee removed!");'; 
    echo 'window.location = "employees.php";';
    echo '</script>';
?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Your `where` clause should be this `WHERE  employee_id = $temp1`